# Arrays with spaces: do groupinstalls from script

Tags: bash, yum

I know, the group names that contains spaces has to be enclosed by quotes and they are, still this does not want to work out as I would expect it:

```
export instdesk="xterm java-1.8.0-openjdk xrdp tigervnc-server"
export grpdesk=(Desktop "Desktop Platform" "General Purpose Desktop" "X Window System" "Legacy X Window System compatibility" Fonts)
yumdesk() {
for ginstdesk in "${grpdesk[@]}"; do
    yum -y groupinstall $ginstdesk
done
}
```

Have tried simply just `yum -y groupinstall ${grpdesk[*]}` still won't work.

Comment: What happens?  Do you need to quote $ginstdesk?

Comment: you are right, I just couldn't see that I was missing it there in 5th line. So it is solved, please post your answer.

Comment: You are not required to export every variable.

Comment: Please read this definitive Q&A about quoting: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667

Comment: Also, this should work: `yum -y groupinstall "${grpdesk[@]}"` (quoted and using [@]) -- at the risk of blowing my own horn, this SO question is very relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12314451/7552

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a space in the value of $ginstdesk, so it needs to be quoted.